# jScrollTo bugging out in IE7 + 8, works fine in FF and IE9

Tags: jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm using the jScrollTo plugin to create this website [removed]

Sadly, I've spent a few hours trying to debug why it's not working in IE7/8, I've tried many things but can't figure it out.

Here's a demo of it when it works in IE7/8: http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html

Help! :( Sorry if my post isn't formatted correctly, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Solution Below

**The  jQuery**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('a.panel').click(function () {

    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    current = $(this);
        //$('#wrapper').scrollTo('#item1', { margin: true});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      
    //
    return false;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizePanel();
});
```

});

**The error round abouts:**

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 

$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.panel').click(function () {

    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    **current = $(this);**
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1000);     
    //
    return false;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizePanel();
});
```

});

**THE SOLUTION**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('a.panel').click(function () {

    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
            *current = $(this); // remove this*
    **var selected = $(this); //add this new line**
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1000);     
    //
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Done. I'm 95% sure it's the menu breaking it..

Comment: Tried $('span.panel').removeClass('selected'); and IE hates it still

Comment: I tried playing around with the width of `#mask` and got it working

Comment: Nice, what did you set it to? greater or smaller?

Comment: Greater, but the problem is that it's not set by JS... I'm looking into why

Comment: Okay cool. I've edited the post with the resizePanel function, not entirely sure what it does? sorry. *sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your first `<script>` tag below the includes of dependent scripts such as jQuery and scrollTo.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't fix the problem, I noticed this before and tried it. Sorry for the confusion